# Implicit function theorem for boundary value problems

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, calculus-of-variations, implicit-function-theorem

I have a nonlinear, two point boundary value problem of the form 
$F(x, y(x), y'(x); \Omega ) = y''$ along with some boundary conditions of the form $y_\Omega(0) = a_\Omega, y_{\Omega}(1) = b_\Omega$. The set $\Omega$ is a set of parameters which both alters the dynamics and changes the locations of the boundary points.

Now, suppose to I have a solution to this BVP (call it $y_\Omega(x))$, and I change the parameters in $\Omega$ a small bit (resulting in new boundary points) - am I guaranteed to again have a solution $Y_{\Omega'}$  that is "close" to the original function in some sense?

Really, I am asking if there is an implicit function theorem for boundary value problems.

Alternatively, since my BVP is derived via the Euler-Lagrange equations, I would be fine if there was an implicit function theorem for the minimum of an integral, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an implicit function theorem for smooth nonlinear maps between Banach spaces. You can apply this to your problem by considering the mapping 
$$(y,\Omega)\mapsto (y''-F,y(0),y(1))$$
from $C^2[0,1]\times (your\ parameter\ set)$ to $C[0,1]\times R^2$.

Comment: This answer certainly makes sense, but I think I am still a little stymied about how to show the mapping you suggest is smooth. Is this just a requirement on my operator to be nonlinear BVP operator to be non-singular?

Comment: In particular, unsurprisingly by BVP operator is the Euler-Lagrange operator. Are there conditions under which this operator is non-singular?

Comment: What you need is that F is smooth and that the linearization at your known solution is uniquely solvable.